# svo_ros + kinetic, no topic publishing

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to run SVO on Ubuntu 16.04 and Kinetic running on my macbook air. Compiling is ok and tracking seems to work good on svo rosbag dataset from what I see rqt_svo GUI ("GOOD TRACKING" displayed).

However, no tf topic nor pose and image are published form svo_ros node. In fact, vo_->last_frame_ always seems null.

I posted the issue on svo github (https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/issues/157) but I re post it here because I think it is more related to ROS.

Because pointers on cv::Mat are involved, I was wondering if the problem came from openCV (version 3 in Kinetic).

What do you think ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239711/svo_ros-+-kinetic,-no-topic-publishing/) by [Rouno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4024/rouno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2016-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FYI I find a solution to fix the problem temporary (I'm sure there is still some topics not published)

I made last_frame_ public in svo/frame_handler_mono.h instead of protected

Somehow the function lastFrame() always returned NULL otherwise.

Now Rviz displays svo/image and tf properly

---

Originally posted by [Rouno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4024/rouno/) with karma: 68 on 2016-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0